# Is it possible to install a Rust (steam pc game) server on xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: server, steam

I'm trying to install a rust server but all the tutorial videos I've found use exe files. I have the wine app or whatever but I figured it was more for smaller programs.

Does anyone know if it's even possible before I get into trying to figure out how? So far everything I've tried to do with xubuntu has been way more difficult than using winamp just because of how nothing works without figuring out the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Rust server  before, but the following links could help you:

[How to host a rust server in Linux](http://www.rustafied.com/how-to-host-a-rust-server-in-linux/)

[Rust dedicated server](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwi2z47ouczRAhUY82MKHa59DoYQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.valvesoftware.com%2Fwiki%2FRust_Dedicated_Server&usg=AFQjCNHn3gAAG4_rvXKsvStZ0VhFpjevbA&sig2=YB0WlVvzu8EdpmgeFhS-gQ&cad=rja)

[Rust server on Linux Ubuntu](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi2z47ouczRAhUY82MKHa59DoYQFghJMAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fgroups%2Flinuxgsm%2Fdiscussions%2F0%2F392184342866723601%2F&usg=AFQjCNFB5K9-sPZd-dvjx1FDtCPJqQ0BvA&sig2=IE27DywZqhIqxqeyZVJcIA)

[Rust | Linux Game Server Managers](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi2z47ouczRAhUY82MKHa59DoYQFghCMAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgameservermanagers.com%2Flgsm%2Frustserver%2F&usg=AFQjCNE4dAYKWFUe2A6POf1UTmtu439LmQ&sig2=mC93fvRx7tDoiJVI6QbxOw) (Recommended)